# Reference Request for Fractional Brownian motion

Tags: references, brownian-motion

This question has been asked several times on this website. But the problem is that all the references suggested are mathematics oriented and difficult to understand. I am looking for a reference, which explains it in easy language but without over-simplifying. I want to understand the basic ideas behind Brownian and fractional Brownian motion, with some mathematical understanding.

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find any text which contains a good exposition of the concepts without making the mathematics impenetrable. Any suggestions would be useful for both Brownian and fractional Brownian motion. I will prefer to read two or three chapters over a whole book on the subject.

I have a fairly good background in probability theory and engineering calculus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Geometric Brownian Motion (GBM)**

For GBM, I would suggest any reputable textbook on quantitative finance, such as [Joshi](http://www.markjoshi.com/concepts/) or [Shreve Vol. II](http://www.springer.com/gb/book/9780387401010). In fact, [finance is where this concept was originally developed mathematically](http://www.nybooks.com/articles/2013/10/24/random-walk-louis-bachelier/).

Let's say we wish to model the price of a stock by Geometric Brownian Motion (GBM), also known as a "random walk". This model can be represented by the following Stochastic Differential Equation (SDE):

$$ dS_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t dW_t $$

Some key points are as follows:

- This is a stochastic process. Although the drift/growth term $\mu S_t dt$ is deterministic, the diffusion/volatility term $\sigma S_t dW_t$ is random.
- The increments $dW_t$ are stationary, **independent** & normally distributed
- It is relatively simple to see that GBM is [both a Markov process and a Martingale](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/The-Markov-and-Martingale-Properties).
- We can gain insight into where the "Geometric" in GBM comes from by rewriting the SDE as $ \frac{dS_t}{S_t} = \mu dt + \sigma dW_t $. By interpreting $\frac{dS_t}{S_t}$ as the percentage change in price (i.e. the return) we can see that movements in the stock price are proportional to the current stock price.
- The famous Black-Scholes pricing model, among others, is based on asset price movements following GBM.

**Fractional Brownian Motion (fBm)**

fBm is a more advanced topic. [Shevchenko's lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.1956.pdf) and the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Brownian_motion) are a good place to start.

The [original Mandelbrot (1968) paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2027184?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) summarises the idea best. With a slight change of notation:

> We propose to designate a family of Gaussian random functions defined
>   as follows: $B_t$ being ordinary Brownian motion, and $H$ a parameter
>   satisfying $0 < H < 1$, fBm of exponent $H$ is a moving average of
>   $dB_t$, in which past increments of $B_t$ are weighted by the kernel
>   $(t - s)^{H-1/2}$.

So we are no longer assuming that increments are independent of one another across time; rather, they are related by a *covariance function* parameterised by the *Hurst exponent* $H$:

$$ E[B_t^H B_s^H] = \frac{1}{2} \big( t^{2H} + s^{2H} - |t-s|^{2H} \big) $$

The Hurst exponent $H$ is the key parameter of this stochastic process:

- Setting $H>\frac{1}{2}$ is appropriate for modelling "slow" processes like interest rates.
- Setting $H=\frac{1}{2}$ recovers GBM,
- Setting $H<\frac{1}{2}$ is appropriate for modelling "fast" processes like mean-reverting financial spreads.

[image]

(image from Shevchenko)

I think it's difficult to "get" fBm and the purpose of the covariance function without understanding [Gaussian Processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process), of which it is an example. Luckily, many machine learning textbooks now cover this topic, including [MacKay](http://www.inference.org.uk/itprnn/book.pdf) and [Rasmussen](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf).

Comment: I have a good understanding of Gaussian processes including the mathematics of it. However, fBM's mathematics is somewhat out of my reach. Thanks a lot for the suggestions. I will go through the references you have suggested. Also, would understanding GBM help understanding fBM?

Comment: Absolutely, understanding GBM (and stochastic calculus in general) would help you understand fBm, since it is just a special case of it. Those 2 finance textbooks should help you with that.